# start an activity without changing the background

Tags: android, android-activity

How do I start a new activity in the front keeping the background as it is and the layout of the new activity is a small frame?? I have seen this in some applications where the background becomes a bit blur and the new activity is started right on top of it... how can I implement this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use a theme dialog for activities, it gives you the look of a dialog and all flexibility of an activity :

In your manifest, when declaring your activity :

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
```

Regards, 
 Stéphane

Comment: Nice. I didn't know this. Good info.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are thinking of a [popup window](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html)? Not necessarily a new activity, though, but you can overlay the window over the one in the background.